# How to run a vbscript in wix burn ExePackage?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, wix, burn

I need to make some changes in an xml file after I've installed a couple of `MSI`. For that I was thinking calling a vbscript using the bat file with the `%*` trick. My problem is that I get an `0X80070001` error, but when I run the script manually it works fine.

Code in chain:

```
<ExePackage
              Id="CultureChange"
              SourceFile="run.bat"
              DisplayName="Changing Default Language"
              InstallCommand='cscript Script.vbs "[DefaultCulture]"'
              PerMachine="yes"
              Cache="yes"
              Compressed="yes">
    <Payload SourceFile="Script.vbs"/>
</ExePackage>
```

I also tried calling `cscript` with `C:\windows\SysNative\cscript.exe` but same result.

log:

```
Applying execute package: CultureChange, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\1608BB75347CD8C40187E5F3C0A969ED73A98D51\run.bat, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\1608BB75347CD8C40187E5F3C0A969ED73A98D51\run.bat" C:\windows\SysNative\cscript.exe Script.vbs "it-IT"'
Error 0x80070001: Process returned error: 0x1
Error 0x80070001: Failed to execute EXE package.
Error 0x80070001: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
```

Also note that the MSI can't be modified so I can't make the changes in the xml file there.

### Update:

I gave a solution that worked on Windows 8.1 but when I tested it on Windows 7 it still gave me the same error.
here is the code:

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c cscript Script.vbs "%1"
```

I also found some documentation on the error:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319335(v=vs.85).aspx

> A write request was made to a resource on the device that was opened
>   in Read mode using IPortableDeviceResources::GetStream, or a read
>   request was made to a resource opened for Write or Create.

I watched the vbscript file and it was never accessed.
Anyway, I went with editing the xml file in my managed bootstrapper in c# and not trying to run the vbscript but I'm leaving this question open since it's not really a good enough solution.